# How to access variable defined in directive to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have to access variable defined in directive and access it in the controller using angularjs
directive :

```
app.directive('htmlData', function ($compile) {

    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).on('click', function() {
                    $scope.html = $compile(element)($scope).html();
                });

                return $scope.html;
        }

    };
});
```

and use $scope.html in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not creating an isolate scope (or a new scope) in your directive, the directive and the controller associated with the HTML where the directive is used are both using/sharing the same scope.  $scope in the linking function and the $scope injected into the controller are the same.  If you add a property to the scope in your linking function, the controller will be able to see it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As you set the variable in the $scope, all you got to do is to bind to it normally. In your case, osmehting like:

```
<div html-data>{{html}}</div>
```

Maybe you're not seeing the update because it lacks a `$scope.$apply()`.

Anyway, let me say that I see two problems on you code. First of, you could use [`ng-click` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) to attach click events to your HTML.

Secondly, why would you recompile your HTML every time? There is almost no need for that. You may have a big problem, because after first compilation, your template is going to be lost, so recompiling will render it useless.

If you need to get the element, you can inject `$element`.